# UIPopovercontroller doesn't show anything on iPad Simulator(xCode6.1)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uipickerview, uipopovercontroller

I am trying to show the UIPopovercontroller that involves UIPickerView when I click a button on iPad. I can see the UIPopovercontroller but I can't see the UIPickerView in UIpopovercontroller
I've already made a ViewController which has the UIPickerViewer in storyboard for UIPopovercontroller.
So what am I missing now?

Here are the code I am using.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPopoverController *userDataPopover;

- (IBAction)setTime:(id)sender {
  DatePickerViewController *viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"datePickerView"];
  viewController.delegate = self;

  self.userDataPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:viewController];
  self.userDataPopover.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(400, 400);
  [self.userDataPopover presentPopoverFromRect:[(UIButton *)sender frame]
                                      inView:self.view
                    permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                    animated:YES]; }
```

Comment: Maybe your storyboard is nil.

Comment: nope, I filled out the pickerview in storyboard.

Comment: Can you include that code?

Answer (score 0):

Try these
0 - Check height of date picker.
1 - Check constraints if you have any.
2 - Can you try to add DatePicker directly to popover controller

Answer (score 0):

when I use following code, it works well.

```
DatePickerViewController *viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"datePickerView"];
 [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil]
```

But there is a problem when I use Popovercontroller.